# Como mover a la derecha los iconos de FontAwesome dentro de un input?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

```
<div class="cajaUser">
 <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe un nombre">
</div>
```

No se como moverlo a la derecha sin que se salga del input y que a la hora de agrandar la pantalla , tampoco se salga del input.

Comment: Por principio input no es un contenedor. Necesitas arreglarlo con CSS o con Boostrap(Hay más opciones). Boostrap tiene unas plantillas que te permiten alinear el icono. Prepend es la clase.

Comment: si pero no me funciono

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he solucionado el problema y esto es lo que hice.

```
<div class="cajaUser">
    <label>User</label>
    <div class="iconCheck">
      <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>

.iconCheck {
    position: relative;
}

.fa {
  position:absolute;
  padding: 11px;
  right: 1px;
}
```